# Converting to Hex in Python

Tags: python, hex

I know this may be an incredibly easy answer but I couldn't find the answer to this so is there an easy way to convert between hex and decimal and binary and hex in python like the way you can convert from decimal to binary with `int()`? 
Thanks in advance for your answers. - Ed

Comment: Thank you Reblochon. Didn't see that question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy:

```
>>> hex(33)
'0x21'
>>> oct(33)
'041'
>>> bin(33)
'0b100001'
>>> int('0x21', 16)
33
>>> int('041', 8)
33
>>> int('0b100001', 2)
33
```